# odoo script does not when I deactivate the developer mode with assets

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-13

I create odoo module to print quantity from point of sale, and my module work fine with  developer mode (with assets), but does not when I deactivate the developer mode (with assets)

my script file inside path **/pos_quantity/static/src/js/script.js**

```
odoo.define('pos_quantity', function (require) {

"use strict";

var core = require('web.core');
var PosScreens = require('point_of_sale.screens');

var _t = core._t;

PosScreens.OrderWidget.include({
    set_value: function(val) {
        var order = this.pos.get_order();
        if (order.get_selected_orderline()) {
            var mode = this.numpad_state.get('mode');
            if( mode === 'quantity'){
                order.get_selected_orderline().set_quantity(val);
                console.log('Hello');
                console.log('quantity');
            }
            if (this.pos.config.iface_customer_facing_display) {
                this.pos.send_current_order_to_customer_facing_display();
            }
        }
    }
});

});
```

my template file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <template id="assets_backend" name="POS UI Backend Assets Inherit" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="//script[last()]" position="after">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/pos_quantity/static/src/js/script.js">
            </script>
         </xpath>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste the following script before this your script.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why to do that?